# how to make BLE autoconnect to Bluetooth of android phone without pairing

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp8266

I am having a Arduino with BLE which has to send some data to any/all android phones over Bluetooth in it's range. My android phone should have a app which i intend to make will notify about data received.

How can i make such android app which auto-connects to any nearby BLE , if found without pairing even for first time and exchange data. I mean how in any application i can implement auto-connect without key pairing.I found that setting autoconnect=true will do this task , but i am not sure.
Any help, even some resource i will refer and clear my doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-requisites and steps are (code snippets in Java):

- HC-XX module or similar BLE-device on the Arduino-side set to security mode 1 and security level 1 (no security AND no pairing)
- Android 4.3 (API level 18) with built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)
- Check on the device (mobile) that BLE is enabled

  ```
  // Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
  // displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth.
  if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
       Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
      startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
  }
  ```
- Find the BLE device(s). You use the `startLeScan()` method. This method takes a `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` as a parameter. You must implement this callback, because that is how scan results are returned. Because scanning is battery-intensive, you should observe the following guidelines:

  - As soon as you find the desired device, stop scanning.
  - Never scan on a loop, and set a time limit on your scan. A device that was previously available may have moved out of range, and continuing to scan drains the battery.
- If you want to scan for only specific types of peripherals, you can instead call `startLeScan(UUID[], BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)`, providing an array of UUID objects that specify the GATT services your app supports.
- The first step in interacting with a BLE device is connecting to it— more specifically, connecting to the GATT server on the device. To connect to a GATT server on a BLE device, you use the `connectGatt()` method. This method takes three parameters: a `Context object`, `autoConnect` (boolean indicating whether to automatically connect to the BLE device as soon as it becomes available), and a reference to a `BluetoothGattCallback`.

  ```
  // Here we set autoconnect to true
  bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, gattCallback);
  ```

To sum up auto connect alone will not do the job as you want no pairing. So security mode 1 and security level 1 (no security at all) has to be set. So make sure by using software sided encryption/auto sign-in that no unauthorized persons use your device

[Read more about BLE in Android in detail here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)
[Read more about BLE security in detail here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-gap-security)

Comment: may I know if this can be applied with iPhone ?